# Dropdownlist SelectedItemChanged Event in MVC4 Razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any event available for Dropdownlist like onChange, etc. in MVC4? Do we have to use Javascript/jQuery in order to make some manipulations like DropwowlistSelectedItemChanged, etc? Or there is a way only using the Razor or MVC4 features?

On the other hand, could you please give me some examples how can I retrieve data and change a label's text with this data according to a Dropdownlist Selected Value? For example when selecting a City from Dropdownlist, I want to get an address data from database by using the selected city id and then show retrieved address on a label. I would be appreciated if you clarify me about the issue above and give me an example to achieve this.

**Controller:**

```
private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
    {
        var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
            .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
                (m, c) => new
                {
                    CityID = c.CityID,
                    CityName = c.CityName,
                    MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate
                }
            )
            .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(
                i => new
                {
                    CityID = i.CityID,
                    DisplayValue = string.Format(
                        "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
                        i.CityName, i.MeetingDate)
                }
            ).ToList();
        ViewData["MeetingId"] = new SelectList(meetingsQuery, "CityID", "DisplayValue", selectedMeetings);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<label>Meeting</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeetingId, ViewData["MeetingId"] as SelectList,"---- Select ----", new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [on select change event - Html.DropDownListFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783344/on-select-change-event-html-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: AFAIK, MVC does not deal in events, only submits and gets. You will have to use javascript to handle drop down list changes, but you can call server-side code with ajax.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In that case, could you please a suitable sample to achieve this? I have a look at on the web, but unfortunately I have not found a good example. .

Comment: Go look at the answer in Alex's suggested duplicate.

Comment: What about populating some items in different colour or disabled on Dropdownlist?

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyProp, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListItems, new { @id = "MyId", onchange = "MyFunction()" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {
        alert('Changed');
        $('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
    }
</script>
```

or this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyProp, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListItems, new { @id = "MyId"})

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#MyId').change(function(){
        alert('Changed');
        $('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to retrieve value from Database by using a method on my Razor. Could you give such a kind of example?

Comment: It is best if you access your database from your controller, put the values in your `ViewBag` and send it to View.

Comment: Could you please give an example according to the code I use in my project (pls see above)? Sorry, but I have never used such a kind of approach and I would be appreciated if you help me.

Comment: I guess your original question has been answered, pls mark this post as answered and post the updated part as a new question, chances are more people will look into it.

Comment: My original question is actually on the second paragraph on the first message and I need a sample for "retrieving data from database using jQuery/Javascript on Razor" OR "Making some Dropdownlist items retrieved from database in colour or disabled". I think you might easily give a perfect example for me so that I can close this question by marking "answered". Otherwise I have not proceed due to lack of required info :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to use jquery here you have a simple example

```
<select id="myCombo" name="myCombo">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#myCombo').change(function(){
   //Here goes your code 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Just remember, this is an MVC question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need an example showing of retrieving data from database instead of static list. You might give an example for  populating some items in different colour or disabled on Dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

You must use onchange property in a new {} side of declaring class property like this example

[@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IpoId, new SelectList(Model.IpoList, "Value", "Text", Model.IpoId), "--انتخاب کنید--", new {@class = "chzn-select chzn-rtl", @onchange = "IpoFilterOnChange();" })]

Answer (score 0):

You must use onchange property in a new {} side of declaring class property like this example

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IpoId, new SelectList(Model.IpoList, "Value", "Text", Model.IpoId), "--انتخاب کنید--", new {@class = "chzn-select chzn-rtl", @onchange = "IpoFilterOnChange();" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use onchange property in a new {} side of declaring class property like this example

*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IpoId, new SelectList(Model.IpoList, "Value", "Text", Model.IpoId), "--انتخاب کنید--", new {@class = "chzn-select chzn-rtl", @onchange = "IpoFilterOnChange();" })]*