# MVC 5dropdown list for push to controller variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

So im obtaining a dropdown list via Knockout and a array json result, like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedGodClubID,
    (SelectList)Model.clubIDlistItems, new
    {
        id = "ctid",
        data_bind = " options: DynamicClublist, optionsText: 'ClubType', optionsValue: 'ctid'",        
    })
```

I would now like to bind this to a string to then use on another controller, and im stuggleing to figure this out

Im trying to use this and then read the vlaue

```
public static string selectedNewClubID(loggedinViewModel model, clubID[] clubid, string exit)
{
    exit = model.SelectedGodClubID = clubid[int.Parse(model.SelectedGodClubID) - 1].Club_ID;

    return exit;
}
```

}

any help ?

Comment: Hard to understand your problem as described in your question, possible to reword or even better if you can share a jsfiddle.

Comment: i just want to obatin the slected value

Comment: maybe im missing a auto postback function ?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783344/on-select-change-event-html-dropdownlistfor

Comment: no luck, all I want to do is bind the selected item to a contraller variable

Comment: Your description is confusing to me. I believe you want to capture the selected value (handle onChange event in JS code) and send it to controller (using Ajax). Is it correct?

Comment: @SBirthare sounds just what I am needing yes

Comment: @SBirthare the only part im doing any differently would bet the list data_bind from a knockout.js array, hope you can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63407/discussion-between-tim-dime-and-sbirthare).

Comment: looks like the problem your having is mixing server side and client side code. what does your clientside viewmodel look like?

Comment: no its all working now